# How can we restrict the hard disk usage quota for domains in Plesk?

Tags: plesk, control-panel

We use Plesk 11.5.30 on CentOS and want to limit the disk space that domains can use. We have quotas enabled for the file-system as per [KB #768](http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/768) and set a hard disk quota for the domains in Plesk (eg 10GB).

However, the quota functionality only limits the system user account (the domain owner). But what about files created as the `apache` web-server user? For example, Perl scripts can create files owned by `apache` and these would not count towards the user's allocated quota.

Take the following example:

```
file1.zip   bob:psacln      5GB
file2.zip   bob:psacln      5GB
file3.zip   apache:apache   10GB
```

If user `bob` had a 10GB quota, he could create the three files above and consume 20GB as the third file is not included in the quota calculation.

So how can we restrict disk usage regardless of whether the files are owned by the domain user account or Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Disk Space limit which calculates all files disregarding their ownership. So `apache` files will be included. The limit is checked daily and once it is over - a domain will be suspended.

In Server settings you can actually pick what shall be covered by Disk Space limit - i.e. would you want domain backup be included in the limit or go over it.

Hard disk quota works differently - it is maintained runtime by linux kernel (filesystem driver actually), so it will cancel writing file once exceeded. But it is limited to particular sys.user